# Is reading appsettings.json expensive?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently I'm developing a .net core 2 application that should read some keys from appsettings.json on each request based on domain. (I have to mention, I have a single solution with 3 projects that share the same appsettings.json) I'm concerned about the reading time of the appsettings.json file on each request. Does this file get cached when the app starts? My Startup consrtuctor is the following :

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
private readonly ILoggerFactory _logger;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory logger)
        {
            string settingPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"../SharedConfig/globalAppSettings.json"));
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile(settingPath)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();

            _logger = logger;
        }
```

Comment: Why not put the config in a `static` variable, `Application` session or the `MemoryCache`?

Comment: I am not sure if it's cached automatically,

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm used to aspnet, not core. But put a loggin in `Startup` and see if it is called for every request.

Comment: The fact that there is an option to [reload on change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions.addjsonfile?view=aspnetcore-2.0) would suggest that it is read once and then cached.

Comment: It is cached, it is not expensive and it is actually a very good practice on the correct escenario. For example, imagine you have some config data or you app is expecting input that may change. You will have to recompile your app every time you wanted to change those values. With the appsettings.json you just change them and voila!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Configuration API constructs key and values using `IConfigurationBuilder.Build` method that builds `IConfiguration` with keys and values from the set of sources registered before.

If briefly, the following mechanism [is implemented](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config/ConfigurationBuilder.cs#L46-L55):

- Internally the specific provider is used to read from the registered source. File-based sources have the appropriate `FileConfigurationProvider`. For JSON files this is a `JsonConfigurationProvider`.
- `IConfigurationBuilder.Build` method constructs providers for each of registered sources and calls the `provider.Load` method.
- `Load` reads data from the source and fill an internal `Provider.Data` collection (dictionary to be more specific) of key-value pairs.
- This `Data` collection is then used by Configuration API when you need to get a value by key in your app.

---

When Configuration API creates the `FileConfigurationProvider` instance, it uses the value of `FileConfigurationSource.ReloadOnChange` property (false by default). If this property is true, then provider subscribes to "file changed" event (in ctor) to call `Load` each time when the file is changed (and so repopulate the `Data` collection. From [github](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Config.FileExtensions/FileConfigurationProvider.cs#L30-L38):

```
if (Source.ReloadOnChange && Source.FileProvider != null)
{
    ChangeToken.OnChange(
         () => Source.FileProvider.Watch(Source.Path),
         () => {
                  Thread.Sleep(Source.ReloadDelay);
                  Load(reload: true);
               });
}
```